# Control Form Error Box Width for different messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with Jquery Validation :

```
 rules:{
     id: {
         required : true,
         minlength: 4,
         maxlength: 6,
     },

....

messages:{
    id: {
        required : "ID is Required",
        minlength: "ID must have 4-6 Digits",
        maxlength: "ID must have 4-6 Digits",
    },
```

I have 2 error messages for this validation.

And the error message is show individually, in ballons over de input:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

     if(element.attr("name") == "id"){

         error.css( "left", "180px" );
         error.css( "width", "120px" );
     }
```

Here I can show a error box with custom width (and left position) - for each error.

but, many fields have 2 or more error messages, with different sizes.

Today - I can put the **biggest** message in the box - and the short message uses the same box bigger.

Something like this:

```
[ID IS REQUIRED................]

[ID MUST HAVE 4-6 DIGITS]
```

How can I do:

```
[ID IS REQUIRED]

[ID MUST HAVE 4-6 DIGITS]
```

Ajust the box width according to the message needs..

Answer (score 0):

Giving a min and max-width should fix it for you so it shrinks when less space is used and maximize it when more space is used, like this:

```
  if(element.attr("name") == "id"){

   error.css( "left", "180px" );
   error.css( "min-width", "70px" );
   error.css( "max-width", "120px" );

    }
```

Comment: Hi Khris! Great idea, but didn't work..  recognize only the min-width. the max-width is ignored. The error box still the same for both messages.

Comment: have you tried applying through a stylesheet document or withink a style tag? I think its the best choice No need to do this via Script.

Comment: hi Khris! yes, originally I have a CSS to control the feedback errors messages. I use this script to control the "left" position of the error box for each input. I tried the max/min idea on CSS too - but, didn't work too. The problem was that the message was "wrapped" - and for this reason - the max-width never works.. Then I put a "white-space: nowrap" on CSS - and its stop to wrap the message - and then - put the "max-width" in action. Tks a lot for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

I got!

With Khris idea and adding:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Without this "White-space" the error box prefers to "wrap" the message to make the "max-width" option.

doing this on CSS:

```
.has-error .help-block {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #da0c0c;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 500px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

works fine to me!

Tks Khris for the great idea!